# Python list of particular file's name

Tags: python

I've read all suggested post about creating a list from all the files containing in a directory but I did not understand how can I select just the one that starts let say with "str" which is the trick ?

Answer (score 3):

This code satisfies your requirements.

```
from pathlib import Path

for item in Path('my_directory').iterdir():
    if item.is_file() and item.name.startswith('str'):
        print(item)
```

This list comprehension will create a list of the filtered files:

```
files = [item for item in Path('my_directory').iterdir() 
         if item.is_file()
         and item.name.startswith('str')]

# to get file names
files = [item.name for item in Path('my_directory').iterdir() 
         if item.is_file()
         and item.name.startswith('str')]
# to get full path
files = [item.as_posix() for item in Path('my_directory').iterdir() 
         if item.is_file()
         and item.name.startswith('str')]
```

Comment: but in this way I can not obtain list of char !

Comment: [PosixPath('/home/marco/PDF_analisys/streigenpdf.py'), PosixPath('/home/marco/PDF_analisys/streigen.txt')]

Comment: Do you want file names or absolute paths? See edit.